# `pair::operator=(pair&&)` error with `auto&` deduced move operations - libstdc++ regression?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, move-semantics, libstdc++

Given this program:

```
struct Val
{
    Val() = default;
    Val(Val&&) = default;
    auto& operator=(Val&&);
};

/* PLACEHOLDER */

auto& Val::operator=(Val&&) { return *this; }
```

---

Substituting `/* PLACEHOLDER */` with...

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, Val>> v;
    v.emplace(std::begin(v), 0, Val{});
}
```

...compiles successfully on:

- g++ 6.2.0
- g++ 6.3.0
- g++ 7.0.1 (trunk)
- clang++ 3.9.1
- clang++ 5.0.0 (HEAD)

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3XIeJeq4wMhGv5bN)

---

Substituting `/* PLACEHOLDER */` with...

```
template <typename TVec>
void a(TVec& v)
{
    v.emplace(std::begin(v), 0, Val{});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, Val>> v;
    a(v);
}
```

...compiles successfully on:

- g++ 6.2.0
- clang++ 3.9.1

**...but produces a compile-time error on:**

- **g++ 6.3.0**
- **g++ 7.0.1 (trunk)**
- **clang++ 5.0.0 (HEAD)**

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OCj2ltb7ghg4RltP)

---

The produced error seems to be related to a constrained `pair operator=(pair&&)` overload - [from `include/bits/stl_pair.h` on GitHub's libstdc++ mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L375-L386):

```
  pair&
  operator=(typename conditional<
    __and_<is_move_assignable<_T1>,
           is_move_assignable<_T2>>::value,
    pair&&, __nonesuch&&>::type __p)
  noexcept(__and_<is_nothrow_move_assignable<_T1>,
              is_nothrow_move_assignable<_T2>>::value)
  {
first = std::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
second = std::forward<second_type>(__p.second);
return *this;
  }
```

- Substituting `is_move_assignable<_T2>` with `std::true_type` allows the code to compile.
- Moving the definition of `Val::operator=(Val&&)` before `/* PLACEHOLDER */` allows the code to compile.
- Changing `auto& Val::operator=(Val&&)` to `Val& Val::operator=(Val&&)` allows the code to compile.

**What is going on here? Is this an implementation defect in the latest version of libstdc++? Or were the older versions incorrectly compiling ill-formed code?**

---

EDIT: as [**AndyG**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27678/andyg) discovered in his *(now deleted)* answer, the error also occurs when a call to an empty function is made before invoking `emplace`:

```
template <typename TVec>
void a(TVec&) { }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, Val>> v;
    a(v);
    v.emplace(std::begin(v), 0, Val{});
}
```

Commeting out `a(v);` above prevents the compile-time error from being produced. **This behavior is present both in g++7 and clang++5.**

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DQRln3UVCOk30sb8)

---

Another weird case was discovered by [**Sergey Murzin**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7013190/sergey-murzin), and can be tested out [**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xXdx5JoO75OS84fU):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, Val>> v;
    v.emplace(v.begin(), 0, Val{});
    std::cout << v.back().first << std::endl;
}
```

The code above produces a compiler error. Commenting out the line containing `std::cout` prevents the error from occurring. **This behavior is present both in g++7 and clang++5.**

Comment: [dcl.spec.auto]/11 "If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed."  So I think your first program is ill-formed. (The standard doesn't say "no diagnostic required" so there should be a diagnostic).

Comment: Fairly certain this falls under the requirement that the compiler only considers functions that were defined before the template it is trying to instantiate.   Could still be a bug as I am not 100% sure on the rules.

Comment: I guess we could argue about whether the use of _T2 in `pair::operator=` instantiation counts as "determine the type of an expression"

Comment: If there isn't wording saying that this kind of shenanigans is ill-formed NDR, there should be.

Comment: Maybe related: [LWG2729](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2729)

Comment: This is another variant of [LWG2452](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2452), I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly a point-of-instantiation issue. If you do something that triggers the instantiation of `pair<int, Val>`'s definition in `main`, then you get the error. Otherwise, it's only instantiated when `vector::emplace` is instantiated, which the implementations at issue here defer to the end of the translation unit (which is allowed, see [[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.point#8)), at which point the assignment operator is  fully defined and callable.

`a(v)` triggers the instantiation of the definition of `pair<int, Val>` because it's needed for ADL. If you write `::a(v)` or `(a)(v)` (both suppress ADL) then the error disappears. (Obviously, `a.back().first` requires the instantiation of  `pair<int, Val>`: you are accessing its data member.)